# Ubuntu 22.04: Terminal stopped working after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, gnome-terminal

Recently I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04. after upgrading my terminal
stopped working.

Terminal is installed and I can see it in my favourites also in the application section, but when I try to open it shows on activities and then does nothing, I mean it fails to open the terminal.

In my application window I have a terminal app and below it this set of information:

> ```
> Soyombo Terminal Mark-1 U+11AA1, []: Soyombo Terminal Mar...
> Soyombo Terminal Mark-1 U+11AA2, []: Soyombo Terminal Mar...
> ```

the square brackets is actually a square box.

If I try to open a folder using right click and *Open in Terminal* it  opens. (any folder) but fails to open directly or via keyboard keys (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

Comment: Create a new account, log in there and see if the terminal can be started there. That reveals whether the issue is in your user account configuration, or system wide.

Comment: I created a new account and tried to run the terminal, but failed to start the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was [resolved by Vanadium in this Ubuntu forums thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2479980):

> You see that the program, gnome-terminal, is not found. Thus, it may not or incorrectly be installed, or the PATH variable may not be set correctly.
>
> Remove and reinstall Gnome Terminal:
>
> ```
> sudo apt autoremove --purge gnome-terminal
> sudo apt install gnome-terminal
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> Region & Language -> Login screen -> Change language to English(United States) and restart

Before change
[image: before change]

After Change
[image: After chage]

Hope your issue is fixed !!!

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem after upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 via do-release-upgrade. I could not launch gnome-terminal. It would timeout and give me an error like:

```
# Locale not supported by C library.
```

I have tried all combinations of

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-terminal
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal

sudo apt-get purge locales
sudo apt-get install locales

sudo locale-gen --purge
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
sudo locale-gen
```

as well as changing the language settings to English (US) in gnome-settings and rebooting many times, all to no avail.

What finally worked was changing the settings for dates under : Manage Installed Languages > Regional Formats > Display numbers, dates and currencies in the usual format for: English (US)

I guess the problem has to do with the way gnome-terminal wants dates to be formatted.

update: Strangely, I can change the date format back to English (CA) and gnome-terminal still works, so it's possible it was one of the previous commands to reconfigure my locales that did it, or some combination thereof. Pretty frustrating.